# In XCode Swift project - Material Icons not showing in app

Tags: cosmicmind

[Screen capture of Material styled screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URewA.png)

I need help configuring Material with my Swift project.

As you can see I am able import Material into my project, however the buttons (except for the switchControl) are not appearing. The assets can be seen in the project's Media Library.

I don't know how to test my integration. I'm looking at the MaterialIcon.swift file because I don't think that the path to resources is correct.

I've compared my build to the examples provided by CM and I need help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods to setup your project, which I think you are based on your issue. You have two options:

1. Clean the build folder and delete the UserDerived directory, as well, ensure you are using 1.0* of CocoaPods.
2. Copy the Assets catalog into your application.

All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are giving the elements a size also.

```
Let Button = FabButton()
Button.setButtonTitle(title: "Button", forState: .Noarmal)
view.addSubview(Button)
View.Layout(Button).top(0).left(0).width(80).height(80)
```